# How can I make a pivot_table with categorical values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, melt

I have four categorical columns In the following code.

Can I do a *pivot* with *values* (categorical column)?

```
 df.pivot_table(index=['DATE','COUNTRY'],columns='METRIC',values='VALUE',dropna=True).reset_index()
```

I have the next error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the aggfunc parameter to define the aggregation function.

To get any value (if its unique for example) :

```
df.pivot_table(index=['DATE','COUNTRY'],columns='METRIC',values='VALUE',dropna=True, aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

To concatenate all the strings :

```
df.pivot_table(index=['DATE','COUNTRY'],columns='METRIC',values='VALUE',dropna=True, aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you! you are rock!